# Integrating gnome-terminal with notify-osd

Tags: gnome-terminal, notify-osd

I'm wondering if it's possible to integrate NotifyOSD with gnome-terminal.

I'd like if NotifyOSD warned me if there was new output in gnome-terminal (if the window isn't focused). As soon as a new output is printed and the window isn't focused, it'd warn me through notify-osd (1 time only). For instance:

[image: gnome-terminal notifications with notify-osd]

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more concrete. Because I would find it really really annoying if `ping` notifies me on every new output.  If you just want a result notification, try `<command>; notify-send $(if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo Success; else echo Failure; fi)`

Comment: I think it was pretty explicit. I want it to warn me if a new output is printed on a terminal which is not focused (1 time only).

Comment: As a workaround you could use the KDE konsole, which has that [functionality](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdebase-apps/konsole/commandreference.html#view-menu). It works well in Gnome/Unity.

Comment: I'd rather have that feature in gnome-terminal itself... anyway, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pantheon Terminal instead of GNOME terminal. It has the notifications feature built-in - actually, I wrote it. Here's a demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLhTmnifAro

Answer (score 3):

**Dustin Kirkland**, Core Developer of the Ubuntu Server posted something very interesting on his blog: an alias you can add to your .bashrc file to get notified when a job you run in a terminal is done.

**Setting everything up**

1. To use it, simply edit your ~/.bashrc file:

> gedit ~/.bashrc

and paste this at the end of the file:

```
alias alert_helper='history|tail -n1|sed -e "s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//" -e "s/;\s*alert$//"'
alias alert='notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/apps/gnome-terminal.png "[$?] $(alert_helper)"'
```

1. Now source your .bashrc:

> source ~/.bashrc

Try it out

To get notified when a job you run in a terminal is done, add "; alert" at the end of a command (without the quotes).

As a test command you can run:

> sleep 20; alert

Example: If you want to get notified when you compile some program, run the "make" command like this:

> make; alert

**Many thanks to Dustin Kirkland for the alias!**

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Would it be possible to make it the default behavior? I'd like to be notified of all finished jobs when the terminal isn't focused.